# Anchor tag navigating to next page instead of staying on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQgrid containing column for download buttons.
On click of button I trigger click event of anchor tag,which calls a spring controller that executes the downloading code, initially i tried with ajax call but it was not successfull, so i adopted another approach of having an anchor tag in my jsp as below:

```
<a href="downloadFile" id="downloadLink" onclick='return navigate(this.href);'>click</a>
```

on click of a button i call the navigate function of javascript which is written as below:

```
function navigate(target){
var url = target + '?param1='+fileName;
$("#downloadLink").attr("href",url)
}
```

it works fine only for one button if i click the same button twice or any other button after it, it navigates me to the next page which should not happen.
I tried to use

```
return false;
```

in the javascript method but then the event call stopped. can any one please help me to handle this scenario, I want to stay on the same page no matter how many files the user has downloaded on the click of buttons.

Comment: When you do the ajax call, does it overwrite the download button? is it reloaded?

Comment: It gives me errors for content-Type and tranfer-Encoding chunked data.
I have tried changing the content type but did not worked.